# Mandatory column based on the value of another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, validation

I have an excel sheet which has following columns -
A,B,C,D,E

If column A is filled, then column D and E are mandatory. Similarly, vice versa , if column D is filled then columm A and E are mandatory and if column E is filled then column  A and D are mandatory.

I have implemented the code that is throwing input boxes for column D and E just as the user enters any value in column A. That value entered in the input box is then set to the respective column. I am stuck in the vice versa part. I want same thing to happen when a user enters a value in column D or column E. Plz suggest how can i do that in the following code -

```
       Private Sub Worksheet_Change(Byval Target As Range)
     If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Or     Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then 
     Exit Sub 
      End If
      Dim com As String 
      Dim comm1 As String 'Specify the range below. Set single column range else the code will error out 
       Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A11:A200"))
       If isect Is Nothing Then
         Else If Target.Value <>0 Then    com = "Enter comment in " & Target.Offset(0, 3).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False) 
         Do While comm1 = ""
          comm1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:=com, Type:=2) 
          On Error GoTo myloop If comm1 = False Then 
        comm1 = "" 
        End If 
        myloop: On Error GoTo -1 
         Loop 
          Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = comm1 
         

       comqty = "Enter comment in " & Target.Offset(0, 4).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False) 
                   Do While qtycomm1 = ""
                    qtycomm1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:=comqty, Type:=2) 
                      On Error GoTo qtymyloop If qtycomm1 = False Then 
                    qtycomm1 = "" 
                   End If 
                  qtymyloop: On Error GoTo -1 
                   Loop 
                      Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = qtycomm1 



         End If   
         End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand your code looking for an intersection with Column D and another with Column E

```
Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A11:A200"))
If Not isect Is Nothing Then
  'Do the column A checking stuff here
End If

Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("D11:D200"))
If Not isect Is Nothing Then
  'Do the column D checking stuff here
End If

Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("E11:E200"))
If Not isect Is Nothing Then
  'Do the column E checking stuff here
End If
```

More logically, pull the `'Do the column x checking stuff here` into its own `Sub()` that can be called, passing `ByVal columnNumber As Long`, then work with the `columnNumber` parameter for all your column checking. That way you only have to write and maintain this code once instead of multiple times.

---

Also note the change from:

```
Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A11:A200"))
If isect Is Nothing Then
  'implied do nothing here, but since there's no comment, maybe you were 
  'going to get to it later, so this is actually a bug
  'unfortunately, without a comment, this code structure makes it really hard to tell...
 Else
  'Do the column A checking stuff here
End If
```

to:

```
Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A11:A200"))
If Not isect Is Nothing Then
  'Do the column A checking stuff here
End If
```

Where you're explicitly testing for the condition you're after, thus eliminating the need for a comment that tells future programmers (including future you) that "this space intentionally left blank".

---

Also, I hope it's just an artifact of copy/pasting the code into the SU editor window, but the indentation makes your code *really* hard to read.

If your actual code *is* formatted like that, I'd suggest looking into [Rubberduck VBA](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/) a free, open-source add-in for the VBE that will among *many other* [features](https://rubberduckvba.com/Features), format your code nice and neat with the click of a button.

*Note: I'm a big fan of RubberDuck, a regular user, and an occasional contributor to the project.

Comment: Thanks . I will work to improve my indentation :)